# BadMethodCallException Method username does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.5

I have a very weird problem. When I'm submitting the form, it throws an error with server-side validation.

> BadMethodCallException
>
> Method username does not exist.

LoginController.php

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $username = 'username';
    protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
    protected $guard = 'web';

    public function getLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::guard('web')->check())
        {
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
        return view('login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $auth = Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['username' => $request->username(),
                                                   'password' => $request->password(), 'active' => 1]);
        if ($auth)
        {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }

    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        return redirect()->route('/');
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you trying to access the input property as method, I mean `$request->username()` and same with password, there is no username method, that's why you are getting error. you can access input with `input()` method like `$request->input('username')` or via dynamic property `$request->username`

read more at [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input)